# How can I set keyboard filter on windows 7 embedded x64?

Tags: keyboard, embedded, group-policy, iso-image

I am having trouble setting keyboard filters on windows 7 embedded x64 on a virtual machine. I have tried updating using windows embedded developer update on my windows 7 standard development machine but it will not allow me to get keyboard filter update. 
I would like to add the keyboard filter to an answer file with ICE. I would like to run the answer file in vm on WES 7. I cannot find any way to put gpedit.msc is not on the WES 7 either. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. When I was setting up the OS I used the template "digital signage". I did not realize that this template was so restricted and did not contain group policy editor. 
I should have used "application compatibility" template as this contains almost all of the functionality I would need. I do not have any worries about my digital footprint so I do not need to use a shaven down template. Lesson learned.